# finding text in repeating tag

Tags: python-2.7, beautifulsoup

trying to get specific text that is in a span class from a web page. I can get the first instance, but not sure how to iterate to get the one i need.

```
<div class="pricing-base__plan-pricing">
<div class="pricing-base__plan-price pricing-base__plan-price--annual">
<sup class="pricing-base__price-symbol">$</sup>

<span class="pricing-base__price-value">14</span></div>
<div class="pricing-base__plan-price pricing-base__plan-price--monthly">
<sup class="pricing-base__price-symbol">$</sup>
<span class="pricing-base__price-value">18</span>
</div>
<div class="pricing-base__term">
<div class="pricing-base__term-wrapper">
<div class="pricing-base__date">mo*</div>
 </div>
```

I need to get the "18" in the line
18

that number changes quite often and that is what my code is looking to scrape.

Comment: Why do you need to get the second one? Do you always want the monthly price plan?

Comment: Do you **need** to iterate? Would you be willing to use a CSS selector? Looks like you might be able to use something like `.select(".pricing-base__plan-price--monthly .pricing-base__price-value")` to get the element, the get the value.

Comment: Let me try that option. Actually i will be getting both the annual 14 and the monthly 18 and populating in a spreadsheet.

Comment: Can you share the url? Are there only these two prices (with that class) on the page?

Comment: https://www.gotomeeting.com/meeting/pricingc

Answer (score 0):

You can use a class selector as shown to retrieve a list of all prices then index into that list to get annual and monthly

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

r = requests.get('https://www.gotomeeting.com/meeting/pricingc')
soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
prices = [item.text for item in soup.select('.pricing-base__price-value')]
monthly = prices[1]
annual = prices[0]
```

---

You could also add in parent classes:

```
monthly = soup.select_one('.pricing-base__plan-price--monthly .pricing-base__price-value').text
annual = soup.select_one('.pricing-base__plan-price--annual .pricing-base__price-value').text
```

Example:

[image]

Comment: The first method works and grabs all the prices, but I notice one of the prices is different in the HTML on the screen than what the scrape picks up. Could they be running some JS that changes the price depending on my browser? If so how do i get what matches what’s on the screen? Thought of running PyQT to mimic a browser before putting it through BeautifulSoup. The second method i get a AttributeError: ‘NoneType’ object has no attribute ‘text’ error.

Comment: I ran both fine. But I get UK prices rather than US. I checked UK prices matched. Example screenshot added.